# Is it important to close BackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Tags: ios, uiapplication

I start a BackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler when the application waken up by significant change location update. is it important to close the task as below:

```
if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
```

what would happen if I didn't close the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is important. Otherwise battery will be drained out soon.

Check the memory usage details of background apps here - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: But my understanding that anyway the OS will give application 10 more minutes to run. so i expect even if I didn't call it, my apple will be killed after 10 minutes.